# Pointer function only returns the first element in Float Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, floating-point, function-pointers

I have seen many posts online, but have tried all the solutions.

Basically I have a pointer function that creates an array of type float, and a temporary float pointer only catches the first element, despite the array showing all elements prior to being returned:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float* foo();
int main(){
    float * temp;
    temp = foo();
    return 0;
}

float * foo(){
    static float arr[3] = {0};
    arr[0] = 1.0;
    arr[1] = 2.0;
    arr[2] = 3.0;
    return arr;
}
```

According to the debugger,
arr = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
but temp = {1.0} after the return.

Any help is most appreciated. If this were C++ it would work no problem; I'm not sure why it's not working in C, I'm a bit new to it.

Comment: It returns a pointer to all the elements, the debugger can't know how many there are so it displays one.

Comment: After `temp = foo();` try `for (int i=0; i<3; i++) printf("%f\n", temp[i]);`

Comment: Correct! Thank you.

Comment: in VS just use [`temp,[3]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2019) in the debugger to tell it the length. Similar things can be done in other debuggers

Comment: As there's no way of knowing the size, you should really have a constant or argument of some kind to dictate the `3` part.

Comment: Steve, "Pointer function only returns the first element in Float Array in C" --> No.  `float* foo()` does not return the first element of the array.  It returns _the address_ of the first element of the array.